# jQuery showing at first instance instead of hide

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I am using the below code for a menu to apear on a mobile css site.

At the moment it is appearing straight away when the site is loaded and I'd rather it load only on request when it is used... Any help? - I know it's a quick solution but cannot seem to work this out, i've tried other forums and searched online and yet to hear a response.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    /* prepend menu icon */
    $('#nav-wrap').prepend('<div id="menu-icon"><img id="logo" src="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/images/mobileimages/hme_btn.png" /></div>');

    /* toggle nav */
    $("#menu-icon").on("click", function(){
        $("#nav").slideToggle();
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: "*only on request when it is used...*" How you mean exactly? Click something that is not visible makes no sense, can you clarify?

Comment: Sorry it seems to be a little misread - I am after the dropdown #nav only to apear when menu-icon is clicked. But when the page is loaded for the first time, it displays straight away.

Answer (score 2):

You could add some simple css to hide the element

**CSS**

```
#menu-icon{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `hide()` on whatever element it is that you want hidden, *e.g.* `$("#nav").hide()`, somewhere after the `prepend`.

Comment: I want to hide and show on click, which it does anyway, but when the page is first loaded, #nav is showing, and i'd rather it hidden from when the user first loads the page..

This doesn't seem to be working? - I've just tried? Any other ideas?